# "among others" and punctuation

Tags: punctuation

I'm confused about the punctuation around the phrase ***among others***. I've come across a comma before, after it, two commas or brackets enclosing the phrase... I know related questions have already been asked, but they don't seem to provide one clear answer for *among others* exclusively. Can anybody clarify which of these is the most appropriate way (I wouldn't bet on 2 and 3):

1. The kitchen includes, among others, a refrigerator, dishwasher, oven, and an electric kettle.
2. The kitchen includes among others, a refrigerator, dishwasher, oven, and an electric kettle.
3. The kitchen includes, among others a refrigerator, dishwasher, oven, and an electric kettle.
4. The kitchen includes – among others – a refrigerator, dishwasher, oven, and an electric kettle.
5. The kitchen includes (among others) a refrigerator, dishwasher, oven, and an electric kettle.

Comment: Isn't _among others_ synonymous to _among other things_?

Comment: Since 'others' is sometimes used for people, I prefer 'among other things' in all the examples above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usages 1, 4, and 5 are correct, and so is the sentence with no punctuation on either side of the phrase "among others". Also, great question! :)

The thing is, any kind of bracketing effect is acceptable. And that is exactly what is done by making use of a pair of commas, brackets, or m-dashes. These are all bracketing devices. So long as the sentence is clear, the lack of any kind of bracketing also works.

2 & 3 do not work. This is about correct/incorrect comma usages.
The kind of comma you're trying to use here is the bracketing comma which is used to interject thoughts into a sentence. It should always be used in pairs unless the interjection is at the start (For example, take a look at this sentence.) or the end (Take a look at this sentence, for example.) and the sentence should remain logical after removal of the interjection from the sentence (The kitchen includes a refrigerator, dishwasher, oven, and an electric kettle).

Had you used a comma for some other purposes, say for listing (then it's called a listing comma), then the rules above about pairing and logical sense would not apply. There are 4 uses of a comma: listing, joining, bracketing, or for removing redundancy. This is all according to a punctuation guide by Penguin.

P.S. The commenter is right. We need to change it to "among other things".

Comment: Well stated answer. In the future, I'd suggest not telling the asker to "read up on ..." Rather, make the point you wish to make. But, good answer.